# How to change background of html range input

Tags: html, input, range

I need to create HTML range input which change background. But I need only part of background according to the point which I am moving. There is screen how I image that it have to work.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/s20oahr.png]

Thanks for help.

Comment: No this is not my problem. I need to have one part with one color and second part of range with other color.

Answer (score 0):

That would require JavaScript. That would never be done without an expert or atleast intermediate level of knowledge in CSS, JavaScript.

I would try to provide you with the tutorials where you can learn the Library, but, it cannot be done this way! It would require alot of JS code.

http://api.jquery.com/css/ (jQuery CSS)

Use the above page to learn how to use and apply CSS styles using jQuery.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I am asking for some solution. Sure I can go and learn jquery for several week but this problem I need solve now. So if someone could be so pleasant and give me some solution. Thank you.